# How can i generate PDF with live editing (Instant edit) and PHP/Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, pdf

i will programming a tool that can generating a PDF.
i´ve generated PDF´s with FPDF with static data´s in the past.

And now i will that the pdf will be generated by live editing.

e.g: the user can look the finaly pdf page and click on the law fields to type the text.

has anyone ideas?

Thanks !

Comment: to my knowledge there is not an open source solution to this problem.  I am hoping I am wrong.  The adobe solution is very costly.

Comment: How flexible do you want your application to be? A generic program would be quite a feat.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to directly edit PDF file in your browser. All you can do is just get input from user and generate PDF file based on it using fpdf(better use tfpdf for utf support) on your server.

Answer (score 0):

How about you use a tool like TinyMce to edit your data ,grab the output html and create a PDF out of it using MPDF or html2pdf